# CSS / JS tabs not respoding on click

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am having troubles with a a navigation (structured with tabs) that is not working on this [page.](https://no.eh-digital.com/en/en/view-RFQs-quotes-orders-and-re-order.html) **but works properly** instead on [this page](https://ca.eh-digital.com/en/en/view-RFQs-quotes-orders-and-re-order.html) using exactly the same way to include it.

On click on "Norway" on top left the navigation opens but is not possible to switch on the tabs "Americas, South Africa" etc.)

This is the `php`i'm using to include it:

```
<div class="outlet__box">
  <div class="outlet__box_content">
   <?php include '../../menu.php'; ?>
  </div>
</div>
```

The `html`of the navigation is this instead:

```
<ul class="tabs">
    <li class="active">
      <span class="h2 tabs__headline trigger-select-tab">Europe
        <span class="caret visible-xs"></span>
      </span>
    </li>
    <li>
      <span class="h2 tabs__headline trigger-select-tab">Americas
        <span class="caret visible-xs"></span>
      </span>
    </li>
    <li>
      <span class="h2 tabs__headline trigger-select-tab">Middle East and Africa
        <span class="caret visible-xs"></span>
      </span>
    </li>
    <li>
      <span class="h2 tabs__headline trigger-select-tab">Asia and Oceanic
        <span class="caret visible-xs"></span>
      </span>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Is the problem related to js? (I checked the console and i see no errors).

Any tips?

Thanks in advance

Comment: The problem still may be with the js if there are no errors in the console (ie you most likely have a logical error). Please post your PHP and JS - We can't help you much without these

Comment: Ive got an error in my console using Edge: `SCRIPT5007: SCRIPT5007: Unable to get property 'contentWindow' of undefined or null reference
stop-video.js (15,7)` just take a look at it ;)

Comment: I can see this error in the console when the page loads: stop-video.js:15 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'contentWindow' of undefined
    at HTMLDocument.<anonymous> (stop-video.js:15)
    at i (jquery.min.js:2)
    at Object.fireWith [as resolveWith] (jquery.min.js:2)
    at Function.ready (jquery.min.js:2)
    at HTMLDocument.K (jquery.min.js:2)

Comment: what is stop-video.js? The title makes it sound like it has nothing to do with tabs. But any JS fatal error will mean none of the JS on the page will run after that. So you do need to fix it, but it's not really related to anything in your question. P.S. Since you only posted HTML, it's also not clear to us whether you actually have any JS which will make your tabs work either.

Answer (score 0):

Put this code for your navigation, and you're all set...

```
$('#language-outlet-wrapper .outlet .tabs>li').click(function(index){
    var ind = $('#language-outlet-wrapper .outlet .tabs>li').index(this);
    $(this).addClass('active').siblings().removeClass('active');
    $(this).parent().parent().find('ul.tab_content>li').each(function(index){
        if(ind == index){
            $(this).addClass('active').siblings().removeClass('active');
        }
    });
});
```